# Benefits of [class="classname"] over .classname for emails

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why would class selection by attribute `[class="classname"]` be used ***in place*** of selection by class `.classname`? Are there any benefits for this when considering cross email-client compatible emails?

Edit: I am fully aware of how each selector works, however, I am trying to figure out if there is a reason selection by attribute would be used over selection by class for compatibility reasons (specifically in the case of a class attribute consisting of one class) due to the issues with css and email clients. This question arose after reviewing a responsive email template that explicitly used class selection by attribute over selction by class.

e.g.

```
.red-text { color: red }
[class="red-text"] { color: red }


<td class="red-text">This text is red</td>
```

Comment: Hmmm...feels like someone's homework.

Comment: In regards to performance it is ALWAYS better to use .classname selection by attribute takes more computation time.

Comment: The form you have is too simple, that form of selection can be used to filter results but what you have is it in its simplest form

Comment: @Paulie_D: Haven't seen a single homework assignment refer to HTML email ;)

Comment: Not homework. My speculation was if attribute notation had a compatibility benefit over dot notation for emails

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any compatibility benefits - email clients are known to have poor support for CSS (not including clients that use fully CSS capable rendering engines such as Thunderbird and Apple Mail), and an attribute selector tends to be considered too much for a basic email client. But what do I know?

Comment: I've demonstrated that they are not the same operator. Choosing one or the other isn't about compatibility; it's about which set of functionality you want.

Comment: I would agree if the question was about the functionality of the operators, however, my question is solely about choosing one over the other for compatibility. As we both know, emails dont exactly follow the guidelines for best practices.

Answer (score 4):

These are not equivalent.

`[class="a"]` will match `<div class="a">`, but not `<div class="a b">`.

`.a` will match both `<div class="a">` and `<div class="a b">`.

For example:

```css
div.green {
    color: #0f0;
}

div[class="red"] {
    color: #f00
}
```

```html
<div class="green"> green </div>
<div class="green bold"> green with other classes </div>

 --

<div class="red"> red </div>
<div class="red bold"> red with other classes &lt;-- I'm broken </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however, this was not the question.

Comment: @Kudla69 Yes, it was. You asked: *"Why would class selection by attribute [class="classname"] be used in place of selection by class .classname? "* My answer is because they do *different things*.

Comment: I italicized "in place of" to emphasize that it would be, in this instance, replacing the fuctional purpose of the normal class selection.

Comment: @Kudla69 My answer is still valid regardless of italics around "in place of", that doesn't change the meaning of your question. If I asked "Why would you use a spoon *in place of* a knife", the answer "because they're different things with different purposes" is still valid.

Comment: @meager You would use a spoon _over_ a knife to eat soup. However, you would use a spoon _in place of_ a knife to cut something if some circumstance renders the spoon a better or even necessary choice.  I am not asking what the purpose of each selector is, and I think that is pretty clear. I am asking if compliance issues of css in emails provide any sort of circumstance that renders class selection by attribute a better choice over your typical class selection.

Answer (score 2):

`.classname` will match this element, but `[class="classname"]` will not.

```
<div class="foo classname other">
    hello world
</div>
```